# Mongoose nested schema validation model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I have following Mongoose models:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
 webServiceType: {type: String, default: ''}
    , siteMinder: {
            site_url: {type: String, default: ''}
            ,sso_url: {type: String, default: ''}
            ,sso_key: {type: String, default: ''}
            ,ad_group: {type: String, default: ''}  
    }
    , adfs: {
            authorize_url: {type: String, default: ''}
            ,client_id: {type: String, default: ''}
            ,token_url: {type: String, default: ''}
            ,callback_url: {type: String, default: ''}
            ,redirect_url: {type: String, default: ''}
    }
});
```

I need to check wheather the **webServiceType** is **adfs** or siteminder. If the value is adfs I need to validate the sub objects  like **authorize_url**, **client_id** so on.

I tried below steps but getting error.

```
schema.path('webServiceType').validate(function(value, next){
    if(value == 'adfs'){
        schema.path('adfs.authorize_url').validate(function(value, respond){
            var validation = value.length != 0;
            respond(validation);
        }, 'Invalid Authorize URL');

        schema.path('adfs.client_id').validate(function(value, respond){
            var validation = value.length != 0;
            respond(validation);
        }, 'Invalid Client ID');

        schema.path('adfs.token_url').validate(function(value, respond){
            var validation = value.length != 0;
            respond(validation);
        }, 'Invalid Token URL ');

        schema.path('adfs.callback_url').validate(function(value, respond){
            var validation = value.length != 0;
            respond(validation);
        }, 'Invalid Callback URL');

        schema.path('adfs.redirect_url').validate(function(value, respond){
            var validation = value.length != 0;
            respond(validation);
        }, 'Invalid ADFS Login Redirect URL ');
    }
    next();
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get different validations / different schemas based on `webServiceType` than maybe the better option would be to use discriminators:

```
const webServiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ /* some common part */}, {discriminatorKey: 'webServiceType'});
const WebService = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);

const SiteMinder = WebService.discriminator('siteMinder', new Schema({
        site_url: {type: String, default: '', validate: (value) => value.length != 0},
        sso_url: {type: String, default: '', validate: (value) => value.length != 0},
        sso_key: {type: String, default: '', validate: (value) => value.length != 0},
        ad_group: {type: String, default: '', validate: (value) => value.length != 0}  
}));

const Adfs = WebService.discriminator('adfs', new Schema({
    authorize_url: {type: String, default: '', validate: (value) => value.length != 0},
    client_id: {type: String, default: '', validate: (value) => value.length != 0},
    token_url: {type: String, default: '', validate: (value) => value.length != 0},
    callback_url: {type: String, default: '', validate: (value) => value.length != 0},
    redirect_url: {type: String, default: '', validate: (value) => value.length != 0},
}));
```

You can read more on discriminators in [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) and [here](http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-4.8-embedded-discriminators.html).

Also note that I moved all validations on this length to `validate` property. It seems nicer and you can read about it [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)

Comment: Did it help you in any way? Or need more help?

Comment: I have used below validation @barnski, it's working as we expected..

schema.path('adfs.authorize_url').validate(function(value, respond){
 if (this.webServiceType == 'adfs') {
  var validation = value.length != 0;
  respond(validation);
 } respond(true);
}, 'Invalid Authorize URL');

Thanks for your help!